# .proto file for DocumentAI Document object

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, cloud-document-ai

I am using DocumentAI API and want to serialize/deserialize the Document object

https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai-toolbox/latest/google.cloud.documentai_toolbox.wrappers.document.Document

to save the API call while developing. I guess I should use Protocol Buffers but do I have to write .proto file myself? Isn't it available somewhere? I am using Python.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, by "Serialize" are you referring to saving the `Document` object as JSON or as an actual .proto file or Binary file?

When using the Document AI API with a [client library](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) (such as Python), you can save the [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.types.Document) proto as a JSON string for file by using the `Document.to_json()` method.

Note: if you use [Batch Processing](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#batch-process) instead of [Online Processing](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#online-process), the results will be in JSON Files in Google Cloud Storage.

Example with Online Processing:

```py
from google.cloud import documentai

client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient()

# Create Processing Request
# Refer to https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request

# Send Processing Request
result = client.process_document(request=request)

# Serialize the Document Proto to JSON
json_string = Document.to_json(result.document, including_default_value_fields=False)

# Write JSON String to File
with open(json_file, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_string)
```

Also, the Docs you linked in your post are for the [Document AI Toolbox](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/toolbox), which is an additional Python SDK for Document AI with helper functions for pre and post-processing, meant to be used in conjunction with the Document AI.

Here's information about using Document AI Toolbox on documents processed by Document AI.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#toolbox

Answer (score 0):

Google publishes [interface definitions](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis) (protos) for its services that support REST/gRPC:

- [`documentai`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/cloud/documentai)
- [`v1beta3`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/cloud/documentai/v1beta3)
- [`Document`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/cloud/documentai/v1beta3/document.proto)

Google's libraries for services in this repo, combine a higher-level REST abstraction  **and** a lower-level gRPC implementation.

So, if you are using Google's Python SDK for DocumentAI, it's probable that the Python stubs for e.g. `Document` are already generated and part of the SDK and you can leverage those. Alternatively, you can use `protoc` to generate the stubs for yourself though it's slightly gnarly as you'll need to correctly configure `--proto_path` to access `import`'ed protos.

Assuming you've (sparse checked out) [`googleapis/googleapis`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis) and are in the clone's root directory:

```bash
.
├── google
│   └── cloud
│       └── documentai
│           └── v1beta3
└── protoc-22.2-linux-x86_64
    ├── bin
    └── include
```

Then you can generate the Python stubs for `document.proto` using the following command. The stubs will be located alongside the `document.proto` source:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--python_out=${PWD} \
--pyi_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/google/cloud/documentai/v1beta3/document.proto
```

Once you've Protobuf messages, you can [`SerializeToString`](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/message.html#google.protobuf.message.Message.SerializeToString) or use the text format to [`MessageToString`](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/text_format.html).

**NOTE** `SerializeToString` serializes to a **binary** format. Here's an [example](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/pythontutorial/#writing-a-message) using it.